# Error creating a batch of documents

Tags: ruby, mongoid

Following the [Mongoid documentation](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/persistence.html) I'm trying to pass an array of hashes to the `create` method, but it throws an error.

The code is:

```
Person.create([
  { first_name: "Heinrich", last_name: "Heine" },
  { first_name: "Willy", last_name: "Brandt" }
])
```

It throws the following error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `keys' for #<Array:0xae4f69c>
```

Running:

```
mongoid-3.0.23
ruby 1.9.3
rails 3.2.13
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That feature was introduced in Mongoid 3.1.0, in previous versions the `create` method accepts only **one** hash of fields as parameter, to create **one** document, since you are passing an array you get the error.

If you want to insert a batch of documents into a collection using a version older than 3.1.0 of Mongoid, you can do it using the `Moped::Collection#insert` method, like this:

```
Person.collection.insert([
  { first_name: "Heinrich", last_name: "Heine" },
  { first_name: "Willy", last_name: "Brandt" }
])
```